# how to generate results from selenium rc

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-rc

How can I generate results from selenium rc, I can see the results in server window but want to get them into a text file.
Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in many ways. Consider selenium 1.x

1. From in built selenium server Log

   `java selenium-server.jar -log abc.txt`  . This one creates all the Server log into abc.txt of your server location

   `java selenium-server.jar -log abc.txt -browserSideLog` . This on also includes browser side log
2. By using any third party libraries

   There are some third party selenium log libraries available (such as `com.unitedinternet.portal.selenium.utils.logging.LoggingCommandProcessor )` which presents the result (log) in `.html` format
3. Running selenium client on any Testing Frameworks (such as JUNIT or TESTNG)
   : if we execute selenium client in a the mentioned containers, they will present the results ( proper results not the log ) in `.xml` files. this is the best approach . This one makes use of `ASSERTION` mechanism

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for the test runner. JUnit should already be outputting a XML file with the result of the test runs. That is what most Continuous Integration Servers look for

Answer (score 1):

By using Ant we can get good Xslt reports..

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Selenium 2, which is Selenium 1 merged with Google's WebDriver, which has a much cleaner API. If you do this, you won't need to run a separate 'Selenium server' anymore and you can just create a JUnit test with one of the available drivers.

You don't want a bunch of output from your tests. Most test suites in projects are WAY to verbose, clogging up build time and giving no information (too much information is no information). Just make sure you put enough asserts/verifies in the right places so in case of test failure you can immediately spot what went wrong.

EDIT: WebDriver was actually conceived at ThoughtWorks as described [here](http://seleniumhq.org/about/history.html). Thanks to 'AutomatedTester' for pointing this out!

Comment: WebDriver isn't Google's. It was started at ThoughtWorks just like Selenium 1 was.